# Copy Image to clipboard cross-platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-platform, clipboard

I have found following code that copies an image to the windows clipboard

```
memory = io.BytesIO()

# Here img is PilImage object
img.convert('RGB')
img.save(memory, format='bmp')

data = memory.getvalue()[14:]

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

**But I wanted to copy an image to clipboard using python despite of any platform. How can I do it ? Is there any library available?**